# How to change source-ip(tcp) in Java

Tags: java, tcp

Is it possible to change TCP header in Java?
If it's possible, is there any [Change Header] method?

Answer (score 2):

Answering the more narrow question from the title of your question ("How to change source ip in Java"), you can *bind* your socket to a local IP address and/or port before you connect it to a destination.

The IP address you bind to *has* to be an IP address that your machine has (otherwise, how could packets arrive back at your machine?). You can also take any unused, non-reserved port number to connect *from*.

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9999));
// or: socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(...), 9999));
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 80));
```

More generally, the answer is *no*, you cannot just randomly change the TCP header. But there are plenty settings that you can do from Java that will affect what goes into the TCP header.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering whether you'r thinking about to cheat the server by providing a random source ip. As far as I know, there's no way to do this in java. 
And even if you have changed your ip address, i think you can not successfully "hand-shake" with the server, which means you can not establish a TCP connection with the server side.